# Coding-Style vs. Style Tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

This synonym to my knowledge has not been around for long but currently [coding-style](/questions/tagged/coding-style) owns [style](/questions/tagged/style) which, in my opinion, in not such a great idea since "style" is a very ambiguous word which depending on context can mean different things. For example [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf+coding-style) has a concept of styles and the term easily can be used when talking about [CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css+coding-style) as well.

So this synonym mapping causes quite a few false tags in any area where "style" can be used without referring to code; it's a fallacious inference and thus i would suggest the removal of this synonym association.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At long last, they are no longer synonyms.

Whoever had this bright idea of associating them as synonyms in the first place needs to be flogged. (I'm not interested in tainting my own horn or hooves by impaling or stomping though, but thanks.)

Comment: Also made [style] a synonym of [styles]. Hurray for pluralization!